# Please help in finding if it is a Conditional or bi-conditional statement

Tags: elementary-number-theory

In the Euclidean algorithm, the basic assumption is the conditional statement that any common divisor $c$ of $a,b$ will divide any linear combination too,
 i.e., if $\exists c,a,b \in \mathbb{Z}, c\mid a,b \implies \forall u,v \in \mathbb{Z}, c \mid au + bv.$

I request vetting my reasoning that why it is not a bi-conditional ($\iff$):

If assume: $\exists c,a,b \in \mathbb{Z}, c\mid a,b \iff \forall u,v \in \mathbb{Z}, c \mid au + bv$,  and take the 'only-if' part then it means that : $\forall u,v \in \mathbb{Z}, c \mid au + bv \implies \exists c,a,b \in \mathbb{Z}, c\mid a,b $

Then it is clear that need <del>prove</del> assume for all possible values of $u,v$, and hence ...

I am unable to pursue further, or apply any standard approach, as contradiction based one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To state the theorem precisely: Let $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$ be fixed, and suppose $c$ is such that $c \mid a, b$. Then for every $u, v \in \mathbb{Z}$, we have $c \mid au+bv$.

The converse is: Let $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$ be fixed, and suppose $c$ is such that for every $u, v \in \mathbb{Z}$, we have $c \mid au+bv$. Then $c \mid a,b$.

This converse is trivially true: let $v=0, u=1$ to obtain $c \mid a$, and let $u=0, v=1$ to obtain $c \mid b$.

Comment: So, it is a bi-conditional, & not a conditional as usually stated. If so, then are just the trivial cases enough for proof. If not, then only for two trivial cases it is true.

Comment: It's usually stated as a conditional because the other direction is trivial. Similarly, the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic is "every number is a product of finitely many primes in an essentially unique way", which is always stated as a one-way implication even though the converse ("if it's a product of finitely many primes in an essentially unique way, then it's a number") is true.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. I hope that this topic with more similar examples is accessible from some source in literature also, & request for some reference too.